# What is the purpose of TPopupActionBar?

Tags: delphi

What is the purpose of TPopupActionBar? The manual say little about it.
How do I use it in a GUI?

Comment: It's the popup counterpart of action controls. The popup property is of TCustomActionPopupMenuEx which descends from [TCustomActionPopupMenu](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries//en/Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionPopupMenu).

Comment: Drop a TImagelist, a TPopupActionBar and a TActionManager on a form. Set the TActionManager.Images property to the TImagelist, and then double-click it and add some actions (see New Standard Action). Set the Images property of the TPopupActionBar to the TImageList. Double-click the TPopupActionBar to open the Menu Designer. Drag actions from the TActionManager onto the Menu Designer to add new menu items connected to those actions. Set the form's PopupMenu property to the TPopupActionBar. Run your app and right click on the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TPopupActionBar is a subclass of TPopupMenu and extends TPopupMenu by providing the option to associate actions with each menu item.

Use below code for create a new...

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MenuItem: TMenuItem;
  Action: TCustomAction;
begin
  MenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(PopupActionBar1);
  Action := TFileOpen.Create(PopupActionBar1);
  Action.Caption := '&Open...';
  MenuItem.Action := Action;
  PopupActionBar1.Items.Add(MenuItem);

  MenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(PopupActionBar1);
  Action := TFileOpenWith.Create(PopupActionBar1);
  Action.Caption := 'Open with...';
  MenuItem.Action := Action;
  PopupActionBar1.Items.Add(MenuItem);
end;
```

Comment: In addition to that, TPopupActionBar supports Custom Styles by default, TPopupMenu does not.